# Bash to Python migration

Tags: python, bash, sqlplus

I am migrating my following bash script to python

**Bash Code**

```
sqlplus -S User/psw@inst << EOF
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set echo off 
set heading off
prompt *****************************
prompt *** Running Script 1***
@/my/location/Script1
prompt *****************************
prompt *** Running Script 2***
@/my/location/Script2
exit;
EOF
```

**Python Code**

```
(username, password, host) = ("user","psw","isntance") 
conn_string = " %s/%s@%s "% (username,password,host)
#for script1 
session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S', conn_string], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
sql_file = '%s/%s' % ('/my/folder', 'Script1.sql')
with open(sql_file) as f:
    stdout, stderr = session.communicate(f.read())
print stdout
print stderr

#for script2 
session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S', conn_string], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
sql_file = '%s/%s' % ('/my/folder', 'Script2.sql')
with open(sql_file) as f:
    stdout, stderr = session.communicate(f.read())
print stdout
print stderr
```

I have two questions,

1) Is there a way to run both the scripts without opening another
    instance of `Popen`
 2)How do I implement the  `prompt` functionality
    in the `python` code?

Answer (score 3):

In Python you shouldn't shell out for database connections. Use the appropriate database module instead, in this case [cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/). Oracle even has a [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html) on this. Quoting the simple query example from there:

```
import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect('pythonhol/welcome@127.0.0.1/orcl')

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from departments order by department_id')
for result in cur:
    print result

cur.close()
con.close()
```

Comment: The issue is I don't have `cx_Oracle` module installed.I don't have access right to install on server where I am running python. Hence the alternate approach.

Comment: Talk to whoever can install the module and ask them to do it. Don't work around a problem unless you at least tried to fix it.

Comment: Ansgar , Sorry I am learning this on my own time(as python comes by default in our server unix intallation ). Can't get the sytem admin to install new stuff on the server for just for me. But I appreciate the time taken by you to answer the query , I have upped your answer :)